# Nodejs http request not getting hit

Tags: node.js, post, aws-lambda

I'm using an AWS Lambda function, and inside it there is a function that has been working without issue until recently I changed something unrelated in the function, and have since removed the change with the function still not working.

Currently it hits the doPost function, logs the first line and then the function always times out (I've tried giving it way more time and it still times out, it's stuck somewhere).

I've renamed the `post_req.write` to get an error and that worked, so I know it's trying to make the post. I've messed with the url it's posting to, and got an error there also so I know it's actually going through .. but it refuses to log any response at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** It turns out there was nothing wrong with the code here, the problem was how the API handles a certain type of bad request.

```
function doPost(request, callback) {
    console.log('gets to doPost func');
    var req = {
        "accessKey": request.accessKey,
        "templateName": request.templateName,
        "outputName": request.outputName,
        "data": request.data
    };

    // Build the post string from an object
    var post_data = JSON.stringify(req);

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
        host: 'dws2.docmosis.com',
        port: '443',
        path: '/services/rs/render',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

    // Set up the request
    var post_req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
        console.log('RES:' + res);
        res.on('data', function(chunk){ console.log('data'); body = Buffer.concat([body, chunk]); });
        res.on('error', function(e) { console.log('err: ' + e); });
        res.on('end', function() {
            if (res.statusCode == 200) { callback(req); }
            else { console.log('status err: ' + res.statusCode); }
        });
    });

    // post the data
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
}
```

Comment: Is your 'post_data' alright ? I don't know if it causes your issue but you need to format your data into querystring with the querystring module:

var querystring = require('querystring');
var post_data = querystring.stringify(req);

Link: [Querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options)

Comment: Yeah `post_data` is fine. Also I just copy/pasted the whole function into a new lambda function, and it's working fine. Scary stuff.